# Silverlight MVVM moving the results from Child Window ViewModel to Parent Window ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

Hi I have a silverlight MVVM application using MVVM light.
When I open the application a child window should popup and upon specifying the condition in the child window and clicking OK button the main window should display the details.

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        ChildPage cp = new ChildPage();
        cp.Show();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

upon hitting OK button on the child window this window should disappear and display a list of objects on the main window. In the View Model of the child window I have a RelayCommand OKCommand.

```
 private void WireCommands()
    {
        OKCommand = new RelayCommand(GetEmployees);
    }

    private void GetEmployees()
    {
        IEnumerable<Employees> employees;
                       employees = from employee in Employees where employee.Name == selectedEmployee.Name select employee;

        Employees= new ObservableCollection<Employee>(employees);
    }
```

The Employees has the required result. But I dont know how to close the chils window and move the result to the parent window. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (in increasing order of decoupling):

1. As you have a reference to the ChildPage in MainPage, you can access its properties.
2. Use [standard .NET events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), where the event is on the child page, and the subscribing is done in the MainPage
3. Use an [event aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) pattern. Several [MVVM frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913946/looking-for-the-wpf-mvvm-framework) implement the event aggregator pattern.

**Using .NET Events**

```
ChildPage cp = new ChildPage();
cp.NameReceived += NameReceived;
cp.Show();

private void NameRecieved(object sender, NameReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
  // retrieve employees using eventargs.Name
}
```

**Using Event Aggregator from Caliburn.Micro**

```
public class MainPage : Screen, IHandle<NameReceivedMessage>
{
  public MainPage(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
  {
    eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
  }

  public void Handle(NameReceivedMessage message)
  {
    // retrieve employees using message.Name which is the inputted name
  }
}
```

Here we are doing the employee retrieval in the MainPage, after receiving the name from the ChildPage. Alternatively, you could retrieve the employees in the ChildPage, and pass them in the event args/message.

Comment: Can you please be little more elaborate in (2) and (3). Since I am new to MVVM framework. If you can provide some examples that would be great.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some examples of the MainPage (the subscriber in this case). If you need an example of what the publisher will look like (ChildPage) then let me know, but it's fairly straightforward. The MainPage subscribes to events that the ChildPage publishes.

Comment: using the events I can access only the view not the ViewModel where the Employees collection is

Comment: Ah, I've just reread the question, I assumed MainPage and ChildPage were view models. You should minimise code behind if you are using MVVM. I would recommend a view model first approach, where view models are in charge of locating the views and displaying them. This is built into the MVVM frameworks linked earlier.

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you give me show me tutorials for that approach.

Comment: If you're serious about MVVM, then I would way up the features and benefits of the various frameworks. Caliburn.Micro is a great choice and examples and documentation are at http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/, and the examples show the view model first approach.

Comment: Is there no other route to move the data to the main page from the child window. Or is there a way to access this information from the main window view model?

Comment: How do you bind your view models to your views? Do you do this in XAML? If so, the DataContext should be set to an instance of your view model, and you can acquire this in code behind. You really should consider a framework though.

Answer (score 0):

To close the child window, you can either use the Close() Method of the ChildWindow or you can set the DialogResult property to true or false which also close it.
You have to do it in the code-behind of ChildPage on the OnClick event of the OK Button.

To access the Employees property of the ChildPage's ViewModel you can do something like that :

```
public MainPage()
{
    ChildPage cp = new ChildPage();
    cp.Closed += (s,e) =>
    {
      //Do something with (cp.DataContext as ChildPageViewModel).Employees
    }
    cp.Show();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: I currently use the DialogResult property to close the window. but when I assign Observable<collection <Employee> d = (cp.DataContext as ChildPageViewModel).Employees it complains cp.Datacontext  is null.